# Why my function does'nt work and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, list

I need to build the game four in a row, everything works except of the win function when I'm trying to win in a row way or column way- the diagonal works. I tried several ways, but nothing seemed to work, it writes rigth away that the first player have won.
the matrix is the array for the table of the game that is 10x10, and who2 is the var for which player's turn now (1 or 2). can someone please tell me what is wrong or maybe offer another way to win? I will be very grateful

```
def win():
    global matrix
    #global winningnum
    global who2
    #one = 0
    #two = 0
    #i=0
    #j=0
    boolie=False
    # shura

    # for m in range(10):
    #     i=0
    #     j=0
    #
    #     if matrix[i][j]== FIRST and matrix[i+1][j]== FIRST and matrix[i+2][j]== FIRST and matrix[i+3][j]==  FIRST:
    #         boolie=True
    #
    #
    #     elif matrix[i][j]== SECOND and matrix[i][j+1]== SECOND and matrix[i][j+2]== SECOND and matrix[i][j+3]== SECOND:
    #         boolie=True
    #
    #     j+=1

    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        boolie= True
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            if who2==FIRST:
                if matrix[i][j]==1:
                    boolie=False
                if matrix[i][j]!=1:
                    boolie=False

            if who2==SECOND:
                if matrix[i][j]!=2:
                    boolie=False

            if boolie:
                return boolie


    # print(one)
    # if one>=4 or two>=4:
    #     # print("win")
    #     boolie=True
    #     winning=1

    # else:
    #     one=0
    #     two=0

    # tur



        # for i in range(SIZE-3):
        #     for j in range(SIZE-3):
        # for m in range(10):
        #     j=0
        #     i=0
        #     if matrix[j][i] == FIRST and matrix[j][i+1] == FIRST and matrix[j][i+2] == FIRST and matrix[j][i+3] ==FIRST:
        #         boolie=True
        #
        #
        #
        #     elif matrix[j][i] == SECOND and matrix[j][i+1] == SECOND and matrix[j][i+2] == SECOND and matrix[j][i+3] ==SECOND:
        #         boolie=True
        #     # print(matrix[j][i],matrix[j][i+1],matrix[j][i+2],matrix[j][i+3])
        #     j+=1
        #
        #
        #
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        boolie= True
        for j in range(len(matrix)):
            if who2==FIRST:
                if matrix[j][i]!=1:
                    boolie=True

            if who2==SECOND:
                if matrix[j][i]!=2:
                    boolie=True

    if boolie:
        return boolie
```

Comment: Hard to follow with all that commented code. Maybe use your comments to explain the code. One thing that stands out: `if matrix[i][j] == 1: boolie = False` then `if matrix[i][j] != 1:  boolie = False` always sets `boolie` to `False`

Comment: my bad, meant the second one to be True, but it doesn't work otherwise too. the remarks, are the my other attempts that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why isn't your code working, but I think this code will work for what you wanna do, if it doesn't, just tell me and i'll adapt it.

```
matrix = [
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2]
]
who2 = 2

# You should already have these two variables over here, they are there
# to test them, if you want to try with your code, remove them.

def win():
    global matrix
    global who2
    max_y = len(matrix) #### Get matrix's height (10 if it don't changes)
    max_x = len(matrix[0]) # Get matrix's width (10 if it don't changes)
    line_len = 4 # 4 in a row to score
    mx = max_x - 1 # Index starts at 0
    my = max_y - 1 # Index starts at 0
    for y in range(max_y):
        for x in range(max_x):
            cases = []
            line = []
            for i in range(line_len):
                try: line.append(matrix[y+i][x])
                except: break
            if y+i <= my: cases.append(line) # Don't count as valid if index is out of range
            line = []
            for i in range(line_len):
                try: line.append(matrix[y][x+i])
                except: break
            if x+i <= mx: cases.append(line) # Don't count as valid if index is out of range
            line = []
            for i in range(line_len):
                try: line.append(matrix[y+i][x+i])
                except: break
            if x+i <= mx and y+i <= my: cases.append(line)  # Don't count as valid if at less 1 index is out of range
            for i in cases:
                breyk = False
                val = i[0]
                for j in i:
                    if who2 != val or j != val: ## You may have your FIRST or SECOND for this, but since i'm not sure i used this instead
                        breyk = True
                        break
                if breyk:
                    continue
                return(True)
    return(False)
print(win())
```

I hope that my answer helps you.